# where condition based on bind variables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want a different set where condition to be executed on a query based on a bind variable in Oracle sql .
Here is what I have tried

Table a contains

```
a_id    primary key
a_role  varchar2(10)

SELECT  * 
  FROM  a
  WHERE a_role IN ('approved','rejected' , 'needInfo') AND
        :bind = 'new' OR
        :bind != 'new AND
        a_role IN ('complete') AND
        :bind = 'approved' OR
        :bind != 'approved'
```

In short i am trying to select roles based on current role which I will pass in bind variable. I want something like

```
    if(:bind = 'new')
    {select 'approved' , 'rejected' , 'needInfo' }
    else if (:bind = 'approved')
    { select 'complete' }
```

Thanks ,

Puneet

Comment: Hi , I am not getting how to begin which keyword to use.I can really use some hint, just point me the right direction.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is really difficult to answer as we have _no_ idea what you are trying to do. By providing a description of [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), in pseudo-code if you don't know the correct syntax other users will be far more able to help you. As your question stands you're asking for someone to guess what you're trying to achieve then for them to do your own work for you.

Comment: It is not clear what yu are trying to achieve.  Please post your query and the ways in which you want to vary it.

Comment: At a minimum you'll need to group your conditions correctly on your WHERE clause - I'd give you an example but I can't unravel what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have both AND and OR conditions mixed in your statement, and they may not be interpreted as you wanted.  Additionally, it looks like the two comparisons to `a_role` should be OR'd together rathen than AND'd.  Try the following:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  a
  WHERE (:bind = 'new' AND
         (a_role IN ('approved','rejected' , 'needInfo')) OR
        (:bind = 'approved' AND
         a_role IN ('complete'))
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be certain because I'm not clear what your original query is trying to do - but it should be something like this, assuming your running in sqlPlus:

```
variable bind varchar2
bind := 'new'
SELECT  *    
FROM  a   
WHERE (:bind = 'new' AND a_role IN ('approved','rejected' , 'needInfo')) 
OR    (:bind = 'approved' AND a_role IN ('complete'))
```

This [article explains thins fairly neatly](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html)